# How to connect socket.io only once for all browser tabs?

Tags: browser, tabs, notifications, socket.io

How to connect socket.io only once for all browser tabs/windows?

**For example:**

tab1: sitecom/home - connected to socket.io

tab2: sitecom/faq - fail connected, connection already open.

tab3: sitecom/home- fail connected, connection already open.

---

but send events in all tabs, or windows, where i can see examples?

My problem is: If I open more than one tab, I get a duplicate of the sound notification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think i got your problem. you want to make the multi-tabs work synchronously. But, i am afraid that's not socket.io's business. you can try localstorage, which is shared by all tabs and windows. you can use it to do what you want.
may it can help you.
http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/REC-webstorage-20130730/